# Override function provided by R package

Tags: r, namespaces, package, overriding

There is already an excellent question on how to override a function provided by a package under
[Override function in R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598547/override-function-in-r-package)

The following code chunk works perfectly and does exactly what I want. I would just like to understand what it does and why it is necessary:

```
tmpfun <- get("ctree", envir = asNamespace("partykit"))
environment(ctree) <- environment(tmpfun)
attributes(ctree) <- attributes(tmpfun)  # don't know if this is really needed
assignInNamespace("ctree", ctree, ns="partykit")
```

Could anyone give me a hint, why the last line

```
assignInNamespace("ctree", ctree, ns="partykit")
```

is not sufficient to override the function?

Why is the code above necessary and what does it do?

Comment: As stated in an answer to the question you reference, you probably need to use `unlockBinding` first.

Comment: Ah, excuse me for the confusion: The code work's perfectly. It does exactly what I want. (I edited my question to indicate that.) I just don't understand what's going and tried to be precise by highlighting my assumption that the last line of the chunk would be sufficient.

Comment: Then I would encourage you to read about [environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) and the documentation in `?environmentIsLocked`. All functions in a package live in a locked environment.